# Cannot install 32-bit app on Server 2008 R2 64-bit using asnet_regiis.exe

Tags: iis, 64-bit

Currently I have a set of web applications that need to be installed (using IIS). They can only run in 32-bit mode so requires IIS to be set to run 32-bit apps. The steps that we've taken to do this work for server 2003 64-bit, and 2008 64-bit, but does not work on server 2008 R2 64-bit. I've spent many hours on this and I'm stumped.

The following are the steps performed to get the web apps installed:
1. Set "enable32BitAppOnWin64" app to true
2. Uninstall old ASP.NET stuff using 32-bit version of aspnet_regiis.exe: "aspnet_regiis -ua"
3. Install ASP.NET stuff using 32-bit version of aspnet_regiis.exe: "aspnet_regiis -i -enable"

As mentioned before, the above works fine on server 2003 64-bit and server 2008 64-bit, just not server 2008 R2 64-bit. Steps 2 and 3 give me the error: "Operation failed with 0x8007000B. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format". After some searching, this is something to do with me running 32-bit application (aspnet_regiis) with IIS which is a 64-bit app. Step one has worked, as the flag has been set in the IIS GUI.

Would really appreciate it if someone could tell me where I'm going wrong, and why this doesn't work for 2008 R2.

Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same issue... did you ever get this fixed?

Comment: I "fixed" this by reinstalling IIS.

Answer (score 2):

I know its a late post, but what I ended up having to do was run aspnet_regiis on the Framework64 folder and selecting the "Enable 32-bit Applications" on the application pool I was using and my sites came up.

Answer (score 2):

In Vista and higher OS's ASP.NET is part of the OS and needs to be installed. You can install ASP.NET from the add windows features under Web Server.
[image: Server Manger Roles and Role Services]

The v4.0 version should work fine from both 32 and 64 bit folders.

Comment: There is also a command you can run on the command line which will do the equivalent action.

Answer (score 1):

Check for your Windows version.
If its a Windows 32 bit try running 'aspnet_regiis -i'   from 
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.0.52707 folder

Or If its a 64 bit run it from
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework64\v2.0.52707 folder